# Emacs - Understand elisp syntax (mapcar '1+ '(2 4 6))

Tags: mapping

I saw this [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/mapcar.html) code:

```
(mapcar '1+ '(2 4 6))
     ⇒ (3 5 7)
```

But I do not understand `'1+` here. it will apply a function to a list but this style obviously not like a function. If means add, the function should be +, what does `'1+` mean?

Comment: (9+ 2) or (2+ 2) does't work, no such function defined at all.

Comment: Emacs can confirm for you that `1+` is the name of a function: `C-h f 1+ RET`

Comment: Tangentially there is also a `1-` function which returns its argument minus 1. That one is also slightly less intuitive when looking at the code:  `(1- 3) => 2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really a function, which means add 1. you can try below example:

```
ELISP> (1+ 3)
4 (#o4, #x4, ?\C-d)
```

The implementation is at data.c:

```
DEFUN ("1+", Fadd1, Sadd1, 1, 1, 0,
       doc: /* Return NUMBER plus one.  NUMBER may be a number or a marker.
Markers are converted to integers.  */)
  (register Lisp_Object number)
{
  CHECK_NUMBER_OR_FLOAT_COERCE_MARKER (number);

  if (FLOATP (number))
    return (make_float (1.0 + XFLOAT_DATA (number)));

  XSETINT (number, XINT (number) + 1);
  return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`'1+` is a reference to the function stored in that symbol, in this case it returns number incremented by 1. `mapcar` applies it to every element of the list, and then returns the resulting list.